# std::string, const, and thread safety

Tags: string, c++11, thread-safety, constants, std

This question has been discussed but I haven't seen a set answer yet. It's partially discussed here:

https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/const-and-thread-safety.html

But the answer still isn't totally clear with me.

If you define `std::string const kstrValue = "Value"` is `kstrValue` inherently thread-safe?

What my research has indicated is that it is thread-safe as long as you don't call std library functions that mutate the string.

Is this true?

Comment: It would be terrific, if the whole question was formulated here, without referring to external resources. Apart from that, how do you plan on mutating `const` string and why would it matter if the function is standard library or user supplied?

Comment: @Caleth ...unless you first `const_cast` it, of course.

Comment: @luk32 Thanks for the input. Turns out I misunderstood the article entirely. I don't plan on mutating the function (or any object that is const in that sense) but was just trying to understand how const "guarantees" or "implies" thread safety.

Comment: @bipll nope, that's undefined behaviour. You are only allowed to cast away const if the underlying object is mutable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call any functions that modify that string, std:: or otherwise. What the article is saying, is write your classes like `std::string` (or a hypothetical `int` class).

By ensuring that methods that *don't* modify the class are marked `const`, you can have `const Foo` objects freely shared among threads, safe in the knowledge that there can be no data races, because there *are no modifications*.

It is slightly more subtle with `const Foo &` references. You don't know if the underlying object really is `const`, or that `const` was added to the reference and *somewhere else* modifications can occur. Access to such objects still needs to be synchronised between threads.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

[[res.on.data.races]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.data.races#3):

> A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects ([intro.multithread]) accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's non-const arguments, including this.